# Build failed error occurred when try to debug specflow scenarios in VST2017

Tags: c#, specflow

When i try to debug the test step in feature file  .. I am getting Build failed
VST2017, Specflow 2.3.0, Selenium 3.6
Nunit 2.6

Could someone please help me on this

Comment: Maybe you can add example of the build error message?